# JComponent Painter

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, compiler-errors, jcomponent

I have this source code, which I know works on another machine, but doesn't seem to want to work properly in my eclipse. I'm a bit confused though as I've added the necessary libraries.

```
private class PainterCloseButtonEnabledBackground implements Painter<JComponent> {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent c, int w, int h) {
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.drawImage(CLOSE_BUTTON_ENABLED, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a few errors with this.
The first is in relation to PainterCloseButtonEnabledBackground:

```
The type UtilityButtonStyle.CloseButton.PainterCloseButtonEnabledBackground must
  implement the inherited abstract method Painter.paint(Graphics2D, Object, int, int)
```

The second is in relation to Painter:

```
The type Painter<JComponent> is deprecated
```

The third is in relation to the paint method:

```
The method paint(Graphics2D, JComponent, int, int) of type 
  UtilityButtonStyle.CloseButton.PainterCloseButtonEnabledBackground 
  must override or implement a supertype method
```

Is this just from an earlier version of java? I'm not sure how to interpret these errors and googling hasnt helped. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: here are my import statements

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipException;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import controller.ExtractionUpdateListener;
```

Comment: Without the `import` statements, it's pretty hard to tell. But likely, you are using `com.sun.java.swing.Painter<T>` which is deprecated in Java 7. You may also have issues with source/target compile level. A complete code would help us tell you more about your issues.

Comment: If painter is deprecated what should I replace it with? Sorry I'm new to this and cant find any documentation. (this is someone elses code I'm trying to update)

Comment: Use import javax.swing.Painter; instead of import com.sun.java.swing.Painter; http://j7a.ru/deprecated.html